# Error 403 from JOOMLA

Tags: php, html, joomla

The site began to fly `error 403` after sending some requests, for example after registration. A person registers, presses save and an `error 403` is issued, with a link
[site.ru/lichnyj-kabinet/edit.html?limit=6,12,18,24,100&start=0](http://site.ru/lichnyj-kabinet/edit.html?limit=6,12,18,24,100&start=0) - with what it can be connected and how to correct ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Have you tried looking into your server's error log?

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing informative about this error ....

Answer (score 0):

You might get some help here.
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=711251